# 301 Htaccess Redirect

Tags: 301-redirect

Need help with an 301 htaccess redirect cond and rule doing the following for all the files in these paths:

www.name.com/wordA/wordB/* to www.name.com/new_word/wordA/wordB/*

we are basically adding "new_word" to the new url string.

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule ^wordA/wordB(.*)$ http://www.name.com/new_word/wordA/wordB$1 [L,R=301]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need to use mod_rewrite to do this. This can also been done with the `Redirect` statement provided by mod_alias. It will also append the additional path information to the new URL.

```
Redirect 301 /wordA/wordB http://www.name.com/new_word/wordA/wordB
```